# Store Hours Controller and View to Show and Save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following classes setup (partly taken from [Store open days and times](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91590/store-open-days-and-times)):

```
public class Location {
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LocationTime> LocationTimes { get; set; }
}

public class LocationTime {
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int LocationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual int TimeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TimeId")]
    public virtual Time Time { get; set; }
}

public class Time {
    public Time(DayOfWeek day, string openTime, string closeTime) {
        Day = day;
        OpenTime = openTime ?? "0000";
        CloseTime = closeTime ?? "0000";
    }

    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DayOfWeek Day { get; private set; }
    public virtual string OpenTime { get; private set; }
    public virtual string CloseTime { get; private set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<LocationTime> LocationTImes { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return $"{Day} : {OpenTime} to {CloseTime}";
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to best write my controller and views to display as follows, making sure to respect any model binding, validations, etc. [See dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4I9tO3)

[image: StoreHours screenshot]

Currently, I do not intend to save the `Time` value if `Closed` is chosen and make the app imply `Closed` when there is no value, but I'm not sure I like the idea yet.

Also, the time interval in the sample is 30 minutes, this can/will change via some app settings, so I don't want to hard code this.

If you need further information, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue you have is that your 'times' are `string`. While .NET does not have a good type for time, using `TimeSpan` is a better option and will map to a SqlServer `TIME` datatype.

Your view models should be

```
public class LocationTimesCollectionVM
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeOptions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LocationTimesVM> Days { get; set; }
}
public class LocationTimesVM
{
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfNotEmpty("ClosingTime", ErrorMessage = "An opening time is required if a closing time is specified")]
    public TimeSpan? OpeningTime { get; set; }
    [RequiredIfNotEmpty("OpeningTime", ErrorMessage = "An closing time is required if a opening time is specified")]
    [NotEqualTo("OpeningTime", ErrorMessage = "The closing time cannot equal the opening time")]
    public TimeSpan? ClosingTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan? OpeningHours { get; set; }
}
```

Note the `OpeningHours` property is optional, but it might be useful to include the calculated opening hours and display it in the view (and use javascript to update its value when an `OpeningTime` or `ClosingTime` is selected.

I also included some suggested conditional validation attributes from the [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) library for validating the values

The GET method would then then be (for a `Create` method)

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    LocationTimesCollectionVM model = new LocationTimesCollectionVM
    {
        Days = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>().Select(x => new LocationTimesVM
        {
            Day = x
        }
    };
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(LocationTimesCollectionVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // ... initialize data models from view model, save and redirect.
}
private void ConfigureViewModel(LocationTimesCollectionVM model)
{
    // Generate the SelectList
    int increment = 30; // This would be your stored value (i.e. 15 or 30 or 60 min intervals)
    TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, increment, 0);
    TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan max = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
    List<SelectListItem> timeOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
    while (time < max)
    {   
        timeOptions.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = time.ToString(),
            Text = new DateTime(time.Ticks).ToString("t")
        });
        time = time.Add(interval);
    }
    model.TimeOptions = timeOptions;
}
```

Your view (`Create.cshtml`) will then be

```
@model LocationTimesCollectionVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    <table>
        <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Days, new { TimeOptions  = Model.TimeOptions })
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ....
}
```

And the `EditorTemplate` for `LocationTimesVM` which needs located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` folder, and named `LocationTimesVM.cshtml`

```
@model LocationTimesVM
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Day)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Day)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OpeningTime, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["TimeOptions"], "Closed", new { ... })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OpeningTime)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClosingTime, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["TimeOptions"], "Closed", new { ... })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ClosingTime)
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OpeningHours)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! Great and detailed answer! Thanks for the foolproof reference too.